# Joining my partner in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-citizens

Please can anyone help me. I’m 23 years old, live in Albania, Europe and I am in a relationship with my boyfriend who lives in London, UK. He was born there. We have been together for a year and today he had to fly to come and visit me in Tirana, but they didn’t let him. His passport expired on June and he had to renew it three months earlier, but we didn’t know. 
Today we decided to live together, me to move to the UK. I’ve been reading online about ‘joining your partner’ but I don’t know where to start. Please help me. Where do I start? Do they ask about my bank account, or only his bank account? 
Help me please. 
Thank you

Comment: One quick note: people can be born in the UK and still not be UK citizens, since UK citizenship doesn't follow Jus soli. A child born in the UK can be a foreign citizen if their parents aren't "settled" in the UK at the time of the child's birth. It may be worth confirming that he's definitely a UK citizen for clarity - I'm assuming he is, but it could make a big difference.

Comment: His parents are from Mauritius, but he was born there and his sisters. Does that make him not a UK citizen?

Comment: It depends on the exact status of his parents at the time he was born, and when he was born. https://www.gov.uk/types-of-british-nationality/british-citizenship has more information. The main question is "does he have a British Passport" with the words "British Citizen" in the "Nationality" section, and the "Code" value of "GBR"? If so he's a full British Citizen. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_passport has more information.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to start at https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk.  That guide has several pages, some of which are linked below.

Note the [eligibility requirements](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk/eligibility).  This is a partial list:

- Your partner must be a British citizen or settled in the UK.
- You must be engaged to be married or to become civil partners
- Your partner's income must be at least £18,600 a year

There is a detailed look at the financial requirement in the [official guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/525708/Appendix_FM_1_7_Financial_Requirement.pdf).

You should also look at the [application guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/application-for-uk-visa-for-family-settlement-form-vaf4a) for more information about the facts you'll need to demonstrate and the documents you should use to do so.

The application itself is to be submitted through the UK's [online system](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome).